# django/apache - 2 separate servers

Tags: django, apache

I have an apache server at `webserver.domain.com` which I want to use to host my django site which is on `appserver.domain.com`

I have not found documentation anywhere that explains how to do this.  Note that apache is required.

Currently I have my site running in development and the apache server is doing a forward similar to this -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName appserver.cppib.ca
  ServerAlias appserver

  RewriteEngine On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  ProxyTimeout 1080
  TimeOut 1080

  <Location "/">
    ProxyPass http://servername:9001/
    ProxyPassReverse http://servername:9001/
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there a way to use mod_wsgi and have apache call my application even if not on the same server, or do I need to run apache locally to serve the site and then have it forward through the official apache server?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [Name-based Virtual Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html).

For your example, I suspect it is something like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName webserver.cppib.ca
ServerAlias webserver
DocumentRoot /www/webserver
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName appserver.cppib.ca
ServerAlias appserver
DocumentRoot /www/appserver
</VirtualHost>
```

along with whatever WSGI directive you need for your django deployment.